# Process.kill() takes much time to kill process consuming much memory in c#

Tags: c#, service, kill-process

I am running service.

When I try to kill the process of that service by **process.Kill()** command, If process is using too much memory than it takes much time to kill the process.

Is there any alternative to kill the process/stop the service faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to kill a process from code? This is generally not good practice.

Comment: @WSC actually, closing process in normal way takes more time to release resources. So, we tried to kill the process immediately.                 But, it also takes time to stop service.

Comment: Yes, but my point is why are you even needing to kill a third-party process from code? That sounds like you've got wider issues and trying to quickly kill a process is unlikely to be the right solution.

Comment: My only concern is to quickly close the process.                                                                    You can say if you have better solution in which I can close process faster

Comment: There will not be a faster way than calling `Process.Kill()` which is why I would highly suggest you review what your actual problem is and try and fix the source of the problem.

Comment: Okay Thanks! In that case need to improve process to complete fast.